# Eclipse browser URL changes

Tags: java, eclipse, browser

When visiting some pages from Eclipse web browser (for example www.cnn.com) I get different webpages URLs...

Sometimes I get (in URL textfield) http://edition.cnn.com/.element/ssi/auto/3.0/sect/MAIN/facebook_rec.wrapper.html?&csiID=csi3 and sometimes even FB...

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

This is called [URL redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection). This is normal, and happens in browsers as well.

Comment: Hmmm I know that, but when accessing above mentioned URL (CNN) I always get http://edition.cnn.com/ and never this one (I got it now when testing): http://edition.cnn.com/.element/ssi/auto/3.0/sect/MAIN/facebook_rec.wrapper.html?&csiID=csi4